# How can I reuse an ordinary html form whose action takes one to a php file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I’m an amateur and can’t solve what I would imagine is a frequent problem in html/php forms processing.

Let’s say you have a simple html form which you want use over and over in one sitting and you want to keep track in a variable of how many times you’ve submitted the form. You need, let’s suppose, to send the form to a php file for various reasons (perhaps to put names into a data base). The trouble is that after you’ve submitted the form to the php file, which processes the form data and redirects back to the html file, doing so will reset your count variable to O -- and reset other variables to their original value -- which I dont want.

Here’s the html file, call it collect_and_post_data.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="formID" method="post" action="process_form_data.php">
  Enter first name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Enter last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
var noOfTimesFormSubmitted = 0;

document.getElementById("formID").addEventListener("submit", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  alert("The form was submitted");
  alert("noOfTimesFormSubmitted: " + noOfTimesFormSubmitted);
  noOfTimesFormSubmitted++; 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here’s the php file,  process_form_data.php.

```
<?php

echo $_POST["fname"].'&nbsp;'.$_POST["lname"];

//do other stuff

header ("Location: collect_and_post_data.html");
die();

?>
```

How do I get the php file, when it redirects to collect_and_post_data.html, to keep noOfTimesFormSubmitted from startingagain at 0,  and other variables that have changed on submission from returning to there original value?

Alternatively, is there some way one can persuade the php file to simply drop out of the picture after it has done its job after each form submission, leaving the user back in the html file?

I've tried using just one file, the form action being  but this doesn't solve the problem. When the second iteration of the form appears, all global javascript variables that were changed when the .form is first submitted go back to their original values.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the PHP session variable to update the noOfTimesFormSubmitted

```
$_SESSION['noOfTimesFormSubmitted']=+1
```

something above like this will enable your number of time form is submitted will store in session variable until the session is cleared